How to dry a cup?
If you wash a cup and shake it out thoroughly so there are no longer any drops of water large enough to move, it seems like the cup ought to dry faster by putting it right side up, since all drying will be by evaporation and water vapor is lighter than air, so setting it right side up lets the water vapor escape more quickly. But I've noticed that cups still seem to dry faster if the cup is upside down, even though no drops are going to drop out the bottom. Why is that?

Have you considered that when you overturn the cup and let gravity take hold that new drops will form as the water runs down the cup, which makes it easier for the remaining water to escape? Also you should really quantify your claim with some data.

Water vapor may also sink downwards depending on the surrounding air, you've certainly encountered fog at some point.

@Triatticus Humid air is lighter than dry air, and fog isn’t vapor anyway but liquid droplets, so I don’t understand your reasoning here.

How do you notice? If droplets form there is enough water to do that. but if, as I read your question, there is not enough water to form droplets, how do you notice and quantify without specialized instruments?

@Chemomechanics you're right I jumped the gun a a bit there, though water vapor also isn't humid air, it certainly what results when the vapor mixes with the ambient air surrounding the surface of the water.

The density of air decreases as its water vapour content increases, so it might be expected that an upright cup would dry faster - as the moist air that forms as the water skin evaporates can rise up out of the cup and be replaced by denser dry air.
However, due to evaporative cooling, the moist air will that forms as the water skin evaporates will be colder than the surrounding dry air. Thus it can fall out of an overturned cup and be replaced by surrounding less dense dry air, so an overturned cup can dry faster.
Which effect will dominate, is likely affected by the temperature and relative humidity of the surrounding air.

@Zeus  I think you have underestimated the volume of water. A 'wet' surface with a film thickness of 10-100 microns, so a wet cup could hold 0.25-2.5 g of water. In my experience, a rinsed cup 'left to drain' would dry in less than 20-30 minutes (in a room at ~20 C, with humidity ~60-70%, and no breeze or draft). Also, the heat of vaporisation at 20 C is ~2.2-2.4 kJ/g (1000 times larger than your value). Thus, 500-5000 J in 1200-1800 seconds, so cooling power of 0.3-4.0 W. I think that should be quite sufficient for a cooling effect.

Upright or inverted?

Set the experiment on the extreme:
Water vapour is a mix of hot gaseous  water with a low temperature air atmosphere in pressure equilibrium, the gas fast condensing into droplets of water; you see them leaving a pot as damp.
Over a boiling pot in equilibrium, such that the energy transport from fire at the bottom to damp air leaving at top is constant, the water leaves the pot. driven by the cooling air stream from the sides, that expands its volume while absorbing the heat from the condensation energy, bollooning against the force of gravity.
The same principle that makes clouds over the sea or lakes driven by the sunshine.
Reverse the pot and try to hold the liquid water at the top by a gas permable membrane. The water vapor is condensing  again and the droplets fall through the air downwards with constant velocity due to friction, while the heated air streams upward is cooling more efficently by the counter stream principle. The heated air straem leaves the pot radially to the sides.
By a first look of an engineers eye, a much more efficient drying method: Stop your dish washer before the drying stage starts and use a stop watch to determine the exact  drying times for the two cases.
